# Match percentage of 2string - spark sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a requirement to check match percentage of 2columns from a table.

For example:

Sample data:

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| AAB | Aab |
| AACC | Aacc |
| WER | Wer |

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
  return SequenceMatcher( None,a, b).ratio()
spark.udf.register('similar',similar)
```

Output:

```
similar('AAB','Aab')
Out[16]: 0.3333333333333333
```

I am able to achieve the requirement by using sequenceMatcher lib but the issue is I am not able to use that function inside spark sql and facing below error. Is there any other way we can achieve the same??

```
df=spark.sql(f"""SELECT ColA,ColB,Similar(ColA,ColB) FROM test""")
display(df)
```

Error:
PythonException: 'AttributeError: 'SequenceMatcher' object has no attribute 'matching_blocks'', from , line 4. Full traceback below:

Comment: Please remove all image and supply the context in text format

Answer (score 0):

•   SequenceMatcher accepts strings along with a junk value criteria.

•   If any of these input strings are None the error occurs. Empty strings work.

**Make sure None inputs are replaced by empty strings.**